# Is the expectation of minimums less than the minimum of expectations: $\mathbb{E}[\min_{k\in [N]} X_k] \leq \min_{k\in [N]} \mathbb{E}[X_k]$?

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[\min_{k\in [N]} X_k] \leq \min_{k\in [N]} \mathbb{E}[X_k]$ for random variables $X_k$'s (or say when the $X_k$'s are non-negative)?

I am tempted to say Jensen's inequality, but I am a bit unsure about the concavity of minimum.

Comment: The minimum (or more generally, infimum) of concave functions is again concave. Since linear functions are concave, so is the function $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\min\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and you may apply the Jensen's inequality. But of course, a more direct argument is possible, see Galton's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\min_k X_k \leq X_k$, so monotonicity implies $E \min_k X_k \leq E X_k$. This is true for every $k$, so $E \min_k X_k \leq \min_k E X_k$.